# modifying Zend_Soap_Server response

Tags: soap, zend-soap

I want to modify the response that is sent when I am implementing a SOAP server using Zend_Soap_Server. I want to change the response that will be sent back because I am implementing the SOAP server for a client application that was written to work with another system but now I need to make it work with our system. The client application is expecting the XML response to be in a certain way. So what I want to do is that I dont want the handle method to put together its own XML response, I want to do it myself. Can this be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is some kind of output buffering trick you could use to do this, but a better solution might be to investigate the deeper cause of why the client is rejecting your XML and, in so doing, you may find a much more elegant solution.

For starters, you should probably read this very helpful article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-whichwsdl/

You should then investigate `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle()` and `Zend_Soap_AutoDiscover->setOperationBodyStyle()` to see if changing the encoding style or binding style solves the problem.